# how to upgrade qemu on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, qemu

I am studying CS 6.S081 and refers to the course website to install tools to conduct experiments.

According to the web, I typed the command

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential gdb-multiarch qemu-system-misc gcc-riscv64-linux-gnu binutils-riscv64-linux-gnu
```

on ubuntu 20.04.

Then I executed `make qemu`. It told me `make: *** No rule to make target 'qemu'. Stop.`

I checked the qemu version using `qemu-system-riscv64 --version`, the QEMU emulator version on my system is 4.2.1. The requirement for QEMU is QEMU5.1+.

Should I upgrade the QEMU? If so, how to upgrade QEMU?

Answer (score 0):

After you type the command

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential gdb-multiarch qemu-system-misc gcc-riscv64-linux-gnu binutils-riscv64-linux-gnu
```

in Ubuntu-20.04

you should actually download xv6 source and get into the right directory xv6-labs-2020 by this

```
$ git clone git://g.csail.mit.edu/xv6-labs-2020
Cloning into 'xv6-labs-2020'...
...
$ cd xv6-labs-2020
$ git checkout util
Branch 'util' set up to track remote branch 'util' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'util'
```

(which I found at the beginning of lab1 T_T)

and then you can "$ make qemu"

---

if it still fails and you see this

```
make:gcc:Command not found
...
make:*** Rrror 127
```

you can type this to solve it

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

---

This answer may help you understand the problem:
https://cs50.stackexchange.com/q/10847

Comment: @Yunnosch thank you! By the way ,"orz" literally means Kneel down ,because it looks like a person kneeling down

Comment: So, you are sure about the "After you .... you should first ..."? I think it would be chronologically better represented with a "Before you .... you should first ....". Or do I miss something?

Comment: @Yunnosch you dose no miss anything , it is due to my bed expression